# Bind failed: : Address family not supported by protocol family - C

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, protocols, bind

I've declared a `struct sockaddr_in server` in my main function.

I pass it into this function to return a socket file descriptor

```
int openSocket(char* ip_addr, int port, struct sockaddr_in* server){

    int sockfd, len;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if(sockfd < 0){
        perror("Failed to open socket: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    len = sizeof(server);
    bzero(server, len);
    server->sin_family= AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip_addr, &server->sin_addr);
    server->sin_port= htons(port);

    if((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, len)) < 0){
        perror("Bind failed: ");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return sockfd;

}
```

The struct is passed into the function using this call

```
sockfd = openSocket(vector->ip_addr, vector->port, &server);
```

However I get the following error.

```
 Bind failed: : Address family not supported by protocol family
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  len = sizeof(server);
```

This determines the size of the pointer. You want the size of the structure it points to, so this should be:

```
  len = sizeof(*server);
```

Comment: Also `len` should be of `socklen_t` not `int`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int openSocket(char* ip_addr, int port, struct sockaddr_in* server){
[...]
if((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, len)) < 0){
```

`server` is already declared as a pointer, so I think the `&` operator
isn't needed in the `bind()` call.

Comment: I would use a local `sockaddr_in` variable for the `bind()`, and make the `server` parameter be used for output only. Or, just get rid of the `server` parameter altogether, and if the caller needs the locally bound `sockaddr_in` then it can call `getsockname()` after `openSocket()` exits.

Answer (score 0):

```
int openSocket(char* ip_addr, int port, struct sockaddr_in* server){
```

This is interesting - you use `sockaddr_in` which has the following properties you need to set:

- `sun_family` -- This must equal `AF_INET`.
- `sin_addr` -- This is another structure with an `unsigned long` named `s_addr` which you'll probably want to set to `INADDR_ANY` **+**.
- `sin_port` -- This requires a server port which needs converting with `htons()`. (Make sure this port is not in use **++**! My go-to port is `3333` for testing...)

It seems you're using `inet_pton()` but I'm not sure it has the same affect for setting `sin_port`. Other that it looks fine.

The other area is there might be an issue is this line:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

The `0` on the end specifies [1]:

*"Specifying a protocol of 0 causes socket() to use an unspecified default protocol appropriate for the requested socket type."*

I could imagine a possibility where the unspecified default is either not correct for your Operating System or that there is no default. I would try `SOCK_STREAM` to test whether this works.

**+ NOTE:** This would technically need `htonl()` but my understanding an this does nothing for this particular case.

**++ NOTE:** If you are writing client and server applications remember to be careful about which owns the port.

[1] http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/socket.html